# How to readjust caxis on all subplots?

Tags: matlab

So I have two subplots with different caxis values. Is there a way to use caxis([-2 2]) so that it could rescale the caxis for all of the subplots? There is a single function that produces each plot, and I want all of the plots to have the same caxis to facilitate comparison.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a handle to the figure containing the subplots, you can do the following:

```
subplots = get(fig_handle,'Children'); % Get each subplot in the figure
for i=1:length(subplots) % for each subplot
    caxis(subplots(i),[-2,2]); % set the clim
end
```

If you don't have the handle to the figure, just use `gcf` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color limits of all subplot in a figure to the *extent* of their existing color limits, using:

```
S = findobj(gcf,'Type','Axes');
C = cell2mat(get(S,'Clim'));
C = [min(C(:,1)) max(C(:,2))];
set(S,'CLim',C);
```

Or with a single egregious line:

```
set(findobj(gcf,'Type','Axes'),'CLim',max(cell2mat(get(findobj(gcf,'Type','Axes'),'Clim'))*diag([-1 1]))*diag([-1 1]))
```